# Program to count the total number of vowels, consonants and words and ask for a user again for check for a letter for a string

Tags: c

Program to count the total number of vowels, consonants, words and  ask for a user again to check how many times a word has been used in that sentence checking in a string.

At this point my code does checks vowels and consonants and after this program has to ask for a word to the user to input a word and check how many times ıts been used in that sentence.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char sentence[80];
    int i, vowels = 0, consonants = 0, special = 0;
 
    printf("Enter a sentence \n");
    gets(sentence);
    for (i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if ((sentence[i] == 'a' || sentence[i] == 'e' ||
             sentence[i] == 'i' || sentence[i] == 'o' ||
             sentence[i] == 'u') ||
            (sentence[i] == 'A' || sentence[i] == 'E' ||
             sentence[i] == 'I' || sentence[i] == 'O' ||
             sentence[i] == 'U')) {
            vowels = vowels + 1;
        } else {
            consonants = consonants + 1;
        }
        if (sentence[i] == '\t' ||sentence[i] == '\0' || sentence[i] == ' ') {
            special = special + 1;
        }
    }
    consonants = consonants - special;
    printf("No. of vowels in %s = %d\n", sentence, vowels);
    printf("No. of consonants in %s = %d\n", sentence, consonants);
}
```

Comment: Side note: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/12149471)

Comment: What is your specific question? Not sure if it is important to your assignment, but currently you will count punctuation and spaces and tabs as consonants.

Comment: You've not asked a question. What exactly is the problem here?  Is it a code review you're looking for (unsuitable here)? Or are you facing some difficulty?                     
                                                  
 OT: What happens when you enter a string greater than ```80```.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems in your code:

- `void main()` is invalid: you should write `int main()`
- `gets(sentence);` is risky as input longer than 79 bytes will cause a buffer overflow. This function is a security flaw and has been removed from current versions of the C Standard. You should use `fgets()` instead and check the return value.
- you only test for TAB and SPACE as special characters, so any punctuation will be counted as consonant letters.
- you do not count the number of words
- you only implement the first part of the assignment.

Here is a modified version using ancillary functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_letter(char c) {
    // Assuming ASCII
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}

int is_vowel(char c) {
    return c != '\0' && strchr("aeiouAEIOU", c) != NULL;
}

int main() {
    char sentence[80];
 
    printf("Enter a sentence \n");
    if (fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, stdin)) {
        int i, vowels = 0, consonants = 0, words = 0;
        char c, lastc = 0;

        for (i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            c = sentence[i];
            if (is_letter(c)) {
                if (is_vowel(c)) {
                    vowels = vowels + 1;
                } else {
                    consonants = consonants + 1;
                }
                if (!is_letter(last)) {
                    words = words + 1;
                }
            }
            last = c;
        }
        printf("No. of vowels     = %d\n", vowels);
        printf("No. of consonants = %d\n", consonants);
        printf("No. of words      = %d\n", words);

        // implement the rest of the assignment...
    }
    return 0;
}
```